# How to enable the rear USB ports on a Dell Latitude E7440 when it’s docked?

Tags: usb, dell-latitude, ultrabook

I have this new [Latitude 14 7000 Series Ultrabook™ (E7440)](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/latitude-e7440-ultrabook/pd). It only has 3 USB ports and two are on back. Kinda a pain in the rear (no pun intended). They are hard to reach when using laptop.

I prefer the side ones like on my MacBook Air. So I decided to move my mouse reciever to rear ([Logitech Unifying](http://support.logitech.com/software/unifying)) and keep the side free. I dock the laptop almost all day at work. And since the laptop is so small, it doesn’t fill up the dock and I can access the rear USB ports. But when it’s docked, the rear USB ports get shutoff. WTF?

I went to device settings and unchecked, computer can turn off this USB hub to save power. I did this to all of them and still the USB ports turn off when docked.

Can I enable the rear USB ports when docked?

Answer (score 3):

The loss of functionality is by design. When connecting a system to the E-type docking station functionality of the ports on the rear of the system are transferred to the dock. Due to this, while connected to the dock functionality of the ports on the rear of the system cannot be re-enabled. It’s recommended that while connected to the dock with this system the [‘Dell Latitude E-Docking Spacer’](http://accessories.euro.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=uk&l=en&s=dhs&cs=ukdhs1&sku=452-bbid) is used to provide better docking port connectivity.

Comment: Documented by Dell here: http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN290782/EN